# Greek Pediment Facades: Geometry involved?

Tags: geometry

The following images of pediment facades appear on many structures both of antiquity and modern government buildings. Does anyone know the geometry involved in the triangular design?

I considered that two numbers of a Pythagorean triple are used, or alternately the top segments are just the bottom segment divided in half.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know about the pediment geometry, but my archaeology classes taught me this fun fact: Typically (but not always), a temple that was $n$ columns wide would be $2n+1$ columns long.

Comment: If you mean the various dimensions (height, width etc.) of a gable (vertical triangular piece of wall at the end of a ridged roof)  by  $\it{\text{geometry involved in the triangular design}}$, then please visit [this web page](http://www.institute-of-traditional-architecture.org/pediments/) and read the section $\pmb{3a}$.